# Laravel 4 Eloquent Dynamic Where Clause

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4, where-clause, eloquent

I recently learned about dynamic where clauses (I think that's what is called) in Laravel 4 Eloquent which makes where clauses like `User::where('first_name', 'Jon')->get()` becomes nicer `User::whereFirstName('Jon')->get()`. How flexible is this??

Can i for example do the following

- multiple columns `User::whereFirstNameOrLastName('Jon', 'Smith')->get();`
- use operator other than `=` like `>=` or `LIKE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Query Scope](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#query-scopes) to achieve what you needed.

A simple illustration:

```
public function scopeFirstOrLastName($query, $first, $last)
{
    return $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $first . '%')
                 ->where('last_name', 'LIKE', '%' . $last . '%');
}
```

Using it:

```
$user->firstOrLastName('John', 'Doe')->get();
```

You can name it as you see fit, and you can use any operator (or any query builder operation) inside.

Comment: This way you could get an SQL injection.

Comment: Hi @vinsa , as long you use Laravel's QueryBuilder you should be safe from SQL Injection. ```Note: The Laravel query builder uses PDO parameter binding throughout to protect your application against SQL injection attacks. There is no need to clean strings being passed as bindings.``` [More on Queries](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries)

Comment: Yes, you are right @JofryHS, this code goes through PDO, it shoud be SQL-injections save.